# ASP NET MVC 5: Session ends suddenly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

right now i work on an already existing ASP.NET MVC Project, which has the problem that the session sometimes suddenly ends and the user gets redirected to the login page. Today i noticed something, the login page is always loaded in the background:

[image]

I don't have much Experience with ASP.NET MVC so i wanted to ask, what could be the reason this always gets loaded. The code is not documented so i could not find a reason for it. I use IIS 8 for deploying.

**Update:**

I have now tracked with Fiddler and i saw something, at first i thought that the session cookies gets dropped or replaced turns out it doesnt. Its there even on the login page.

**Update 2:**

I have now validated that the cookie is still in place and the login info is still stored after this forced logout. Is there a common issue in ASP NET which can cause that a session is still saved but not recognized anymore? Turns out it could be this ActionFilter:

```
namespace backend.Models.ActionFilter
{
    public class HasUserId : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session is not there anymore");
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Account" }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 3:**

I think I have found the problem, the session state gets stored 'In-process' i have now changed it to 'State Service'. I hope this will solve my problem. Is it normal that the login still works even when the 'ASP NET State Service' is halted? This is my config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState 
        mode="StateServer" 
        stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
        stateNetworkTimeout="20" 
        timeout="240">
    </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This isn't really a question about programming or about ASP.NET MVC. It's a question about your web site, which we don't have any familiarity with. Maybe you could use Chrome dev tools to watch the traffic and see when the resources from the Login folder are being requested.

Comment: The strange thing is that i have now tested on an other system and there this entry does not exist.

Comment: The session can end for several reasons ( if the app has been recycled because there has been a lot of exceptions in a short time, if the app restarts, if you store your sessions in redis then if you restarts redis you will loose them all ... ) it depends on your design

Comment: The app uses the standard Sessions from ASP NET, no additional Database or something special. What i could find out is that on the system where this entry is missing the session end does not occure. And on the system where it happens the session end occurs.

Comment: I have now tracked with Fiddler and i saw something, at first i thought that the session cookies gets dropped or replaced turns out it doesnt. Its there even on the login page.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs if the login page is as the start page. You can change this by modifying the filter file and specifically in routes.MapRoute.

For more information you can view [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

If you want to change redirection via IIS, you can not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the link i'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my problem was to change the handling of the session state from 'In-process' to 'Out-of-process'.